# How to localize identity error message in .NET 6.0

Tags: c#

I am trying to localize standard identity error messages. I have seen several discussions about this topic. I did manage to create a project and use my own translations and failed on translating standard identity error messages. I decided to create a new project to focus on identity errors. The constructor **MultilanguageIdentityErrorDescriber** is getting called and returns expected value. When I go to https://localhost:7067/Identity/Account/Register and type "test" into email field standard error "**The Email field is not a valid e-mail address.**" is shown. I appreciate when somebody can guide me into the right directions or send me some links. After a few hours I have decided to ask you guys here. Thanks!

Program.cs

```
using Localizer.Data;
using Localizer.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddErrorDescriber<MultilanguageIdentityErrorDescriber>()    
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

MultilanguageIdentityErrorDescriber.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization;

public class MultilanguageIdentityErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _localizer;

    public MultilanguageIdentityErrorDescriber(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer)
    {        
        _localizer = localizer;
        // ckecking identityError.Description which returns expected value
        var identityError = new IdentityError();
        identityError = this.InvalidEmail("email@email.com");
        
    }

    public override IdentityError DuplicateEmail(string email)
    {
        return new IdentityError()
        {
            Code = nameof(DuplicateEmail),
            Description = string.Format(_localizer["Email {0} is already taken."], email)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError DuplicateUserName(string userName)
    {

        return new IdentityError()
        {
            Code = nameof(DuplicateEmail),
            Description = string.Format(_localizer["Email {0} is already taken."], userName)
        };
    }

    public override IdentityError InvalidEmail(string email) 
    {
        return new IdentityError 
        { 
            Code = nameof(InvalidEmail), 
            Description = string.Format(_localizer["Email '{email}' is invalid."], email)
        }; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in my project and I also couldn't find a way to translate the Identity error messages, so I made a workaround that didn't look pretty but it solve my problem, I made a Class with a method that checks the error code and sets a custom messagem, so I can not only translate but also define my own error messages. I did it to translate to Brazilian portuguese,
here is the code:

```
public class TranslateIdentityErrors 
{
    public string TranslateErrorMessage(string codeError)
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        switch (codeError)
        {
            case "DefaultError":
                message =  "Um erro desconhecido ocorreu.";
                break;
            case "ConcurrencyFailure":
                message = "Falha de concorrência otimista, o objeto foi modificado.";
                break;
            case "InvalidToken":
                message = "Token inválido.";
                break;
            case "LoginAlreadyAssociated":
                message = "Já existe um usuário com este login.";
                break;
            case "InvalidUserName":
                message = $"Este login é inválido, um login deve conter apenas letras ou dígitos.";
                break;
            case "InvalidEmail":
                message = "E-mail inválido.";
                break;
            case "DuplicateUserName":
                message = "Este login já está sendo utilizado.";
                break;
            case "DuplicateEmail":
                message = $"Este email já está sendo utilizado.";
                break;
            case "InvalidRoleName":
                message = "Esta permissão é inválida.";
                break;
            case "DuplicateRoleName":
                message = "Esta permissão já está sendo Utilizada";
                break;                
            case "UserAlreadyInRole":
                message = "Usuário já possui esta permissão.";
                break;
            case "UserNotInRole":
                message = "Usuário não tem esta permissão.";
                break;
            case "UserLockoutNotEnabled":
                message = "Lockout não está habilitado para este usuário.";
                break;
            case "UserAlreadyHasPassword":
                message = "Usuário já possui uma senha definida.";
                break;
            case "PasswordMismatch":
                message = "Senha incorreta.";
                break;
            case "PasswordTooShort":
                message = "Senha muito curta.";
                break;
            case "PasswordRequiresNonAlphanumeric":
                message = "Senhas devem conter ao menos um caracter não alfanumérico.";
                break;
            case "PasswordRequiresDigit":
                message = "Senhas devem conter ao menos um digito ('0'-'9').";
                break;
            case "PasswordRequiresLower":
                message = "Senhas devem conter ao menos um caracter em caixa baixa ('a'-'z').";
                break;
            case "PasswordRequiresUpper":
                message = "Senhas devem conter ao menos um caracter em caixa alta ('A'-'Z').";
                break;
            default:
                message = "Um erro desconhecido ocorreu.";
                break;

        }
        return message;
    }
    
}
```

}

To use this method i go to where the error messages are passed to modelstate and change the code from this:

```
 var changePasswordResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, Input.OldPassword, Input.NewPassword);
        if (!changePasswordResult.Succeeded)
        {
            foreach (var error in changePasswordResult.Errors)
            {                    
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

to this:

```
var changePasswordResult = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, Input.OldPassword, Input.NewPassword);
        if (!changePasswordResult.Succeeded)
        {
            TranslateIdentityErrors translateErrors = new();
            foreach (var error in changePasswordResult.Errors)
            {                    
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, translateErrors.TranslateErrorMessage(error.Code));
            }
            return Page();
        }
```